# why app inventor not redirecting to google maps

Tags: javascript, html, webview, app-inventor

hello am trying to use my website an app inside webview for now ,the problem i have a button with location info lat,lang in page , when  i use the website on google chrome the button open up the google maps app  in mobile , but when i use it inside the webview of app Inventor it opens maps like new tab in browser inside the same webview   , which having problem with location permission tried to make the button to open the native map app inside mobile webview no luck here is my page button code.

````
 <button   class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-block btn-rounded shadow" onclick="mapsSelector()"  ><span>GooGle Map</span></button>   


 <script>
    function mapsSelector() {
  if /* if we're on iOS, open in Apple Maps */
    ((navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) || 
     (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPad") != -1) || 
     (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPod") != -1))
    window.open("maps://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=31.9539,35.9106&amp;ll=");
else /* else use Google */
  window.open("https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=31.9539,35.9106&amp;ll=");
}

    </script>```
````

Comment: Please add punctuation to your wall of text to make it readable and more important understandable...

Answer (score 0):

To open the Google Maps app you have to use the [activity starter](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/activitystarter.html), but this is not easily possible from inside a webviewer component.

You could try to use the WebviewString property of the Webviewer component to pass the coordinates from the webviewr back to App Invenor and from there open Google Maps using the activity starter component.

More about working with the WebViewString see here
[How does the property Webviewer.WebViewString work?](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2webviewstring)
see also some examples here https://puravidaapps.com/tutorials.php#html
and the FAQ about [JavaScript stunts](https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/faq-section-javascript-stunts/1717)

Alternatively to open the Google Maps app, you probably could use the Map component, see also http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/maps.html